# Possibility of finding a fifth degree interpolating polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation, hermite-polynomials

Q: Show that there is no polynomial $p_5$ such that $p_5(-1)=1$, $p_5(0)=0$, $p_5(1)=1$, $p_5''(-1)=0$, $p_5''(0)=0$, $p_5''(1)=0$, but that if the first condition is replaced by $p_5(-1)=-1$, then there are infinitely many polynomials.

My attempt was to form a Hermite interpolating polynomial. Although I don't know how to deal with the second derivative data points. The polynomials $H_i$'s that are multiplied with the non-derivative data points in Hermite polynomials came to be

\begin{align*}
H_0=& \frac{1}{4}x^2(x-1)^2(-\frac{9}{2}x-\frac{7}{2})\\
H_1=&(1-x^2)^2\\
H_2=&\frac{1}{4}x^2(x+1)^2(4-3x)&
\end{align*}

I also determined the $K_i$'s that are multiplied with the first-derivative data points. But since  those points aren't given I got a feeling that the $K_i$'s aren't necessary to answer this particular question. So

$$p_5(x)=\sum_{i=0}^2H_i(x)p_5(x_i)+K_i(x)p_5'(x_i)$$

How do proceed form here?

Comment: Why not just use the standard basis of monomials?

Comment: Hint: express the problem as a linear system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $p_5$ is a fifth degree polynomial, $p''_5$ is of third degree and we know its three roots. Then
$$p''_5(x)=ax(x-1)(x+1)=ax^3-ax$$
We can now integrate twice to find $p_5$
\begin{align}p'_5(x)&=\frac{ax^4}{4}-\frac{ax^2}{2}+b\\p_5(x)&=\frac{ax^5}{20}-\frac{ax^3}{6}+bx+c\end{align}
Since $p_5(0)=0$, then $c=0$.
$$p_5(x)=\frac{ax^5}{20}-\frac{ax^3}{6}+bx$$
Now $p_5$ is an odd function where $$p_5(-x)=-p_5(x)$$
If $p_5(-1)=p_5(1)\neq0$, there is no solution. If $p_5(-1)=-p_5(1)$, the number of solutions is infinite.